# Scraping particular data from a website using Beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape only the guitar chords of a song from this url https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/jason-mraz/im-yours-chords-373896 and simply print it.

But I don't get any output while printing it out. What am i doing wrong here? Below is my code.

```
        import requests
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
        url = 'https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/jason-mraz/im-yours-chords-373896'
        headers = {
        'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
         Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
    }
        r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
       results = soup.find("div", {"class": "_4cjjy"})
       links = results.findAll("header", {"class": "_2jxI1"})
       for item in links:
           print("Chords: ", item)
```

Comment: where is ```results = soup.find("div", {"class": "_4cjjy"})```, ```links = results.findAll("header", {"class": "_2jxI1"})``` on the website?

Comment: can you show a picture of what you want.

Comment: @coderoftheday I tried uploading the picture.. but stackoverflow says .. you need to earn 10 points before being to able to upload picture along with the question.

Comment: it seems as if the page is being loaded by JavaScript so you'll need selenium

Comment: @coderoftheday You can go the link I gave and inspect below "Chords" and under "Guitar" .. The umm chords along with the graphical represntation underneath is given there

Comment: @coderoftheday Ok i've nevere heard of selenium .. its similar to BS?

Comment: selenium is a tool where you can automate browsers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to install `selenium` and `chromedriver`

Use selenium to get the html, then do the rest as normal with bs4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



url = 'https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/jason-mraz/im-yours-chords-373896'

BrowserOptions = Options()
BrowserOptions.add_argument("--headless")
Browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'chromedriver.exe',options=BrowserOptions)
Browser.get(url)

html_source_code = Browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML;")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source_code, 'html.parser')
links = soup.findAll("span",class_= "_3bHP1 _3ffP6")

for item in links:
    print("Chords: ", item.text)
```

Output:

```
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  A7
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Dsus4
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  D
Chords:  C
Chords:  A7
Chords:  G
Chords:  Bm
Chords:  Em
Chords:  D
Chords:  C
Chords:  A7
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Dsus4
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  D
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  G
Chords:  D
Chords:  Dsus4
Chords:  Em
Chords:  C
Chords:  A7
```

Example HTML Code

```
<span class="_3bHP1 _3ffP6" data-name="G" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">G</span>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225864/discussion-on-answer-by-coderoftheday-scrapping-particular-data-from-a-website-u).